# Mysql query JOIN query, getting same column comparing id with request1 and and request2

Tags: mysql, inner-join

```
select pr.REQUEST_ID, pr.REQUESTER_ID, pr.REQUEST_SUBJECT, pr.REQUEST_TO, pr.DOMAIN_ID,pr.SUB_DOMAIN_ID, do.domain_name, sd.sub_domain_name, ud.user_first_name, d.user_last_name 
from professional_requests as pr 
  INNER JOIN domain as do 
    ON do.domain_id=pr.DOMAIN_ID 
  INNER JOIN subdomain as sd 
    ON sd.sub_domain_id=pr.SUB_DOMAIN_ID 
  INNER JOIN user_details as ud 
    ON ud.user_id = pr.REQUEST_TO 
       ud.user_id = pr.REQUESTER_ID 
where pr.IS_ACTIVE='1' 
limit 0, 10
```

I need to take out `user_first_name` and `user_last_name` from the table `user_details` twice comparing with `user_details.user_id = professional_requests.REQUEST_TO` and `user_details.user_id = professional_requests.REQUESTER_ID`

Problem is I can only get `user_first_name, user_last_name` of `REQUEST_TO`, I cannot get them of `REQUESTER_ID`.

Answer (score 0):

You need one more join to `user_details` table:

```
SELECT pr.REQUEST_ID, pr.REQUESTER_ID, pr.REQUEST_SUBJECT, pr.REQUEST_TO, pr.DOMAIN_ID,pr.SUB_DOMAIN_ID, do.domain_name, sd.sub_domain_name
     , ud1.user_first_name  AS request_TO_first_name
     , ud1.user_last_name   AS request_TO_last_name
     , ud2.user_first_name  AS requester_ID_first_name
     , ud2.user_last_name   AS requester_ID_last_name
FROM professional_requests AS pr 
  INNER JOIN domain AS do 
    ON do.domain_id=pr.DOMAIN_ID 
  INNER JOIN subdomain AS sd 
    ON sd.sub_domain_id=pr.SUB_DOMAIN_ID 
  INNER JOIN user_details AS ud1 
    ON ud1.user_id = pr.REQUEST_TO 
  INNER JOIN user_details AS ud2 
    ON ud2.user_id = pr.REQUESTER_ID 
WHERE pr.IS_ACTIVE='1' 
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: I see you have asked 4-5 questions and some have been answered. Read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) and note that it's good to mark answers to you questions as accepted if they solved the problem or vote them (up or down) if they were helpful. You can also vote up or down on other people's questions (and answers).